# How to prevent changing stroke every time in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, layers, icon, adobe-xd

I have created some icons in Ai, and I want to use them in **Adobe Xd**. I am trying to import a SVG file in Adobe XD. It's a tool for UI Designs. I am able to import in Ai but I don't want to change its stroke when I try to transform the icons/SVG in **Adobe Xd**.

This is what I am doing so far

1. Importing the icon in Ai as a SVG format.
2. Importing the SVG icon in **Adobe Xd**
3. `Object` > `Path` > `Outline Stroke` in Adobe Xd to prevent the stroke changing

But my question is, how do I first import it into Ai?
Note: I know I can do the same in Ai as well. But is there any other way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  I'm not sure I understand your question. You say the first step is importing into AI, but then ask how to import into AI. Haven't you already done that?  What do you mean by "prevent changing strokes"?  Why are you trying to do this? What is the goal you are trying to achieve? What is the actual problem you are having? Under what circumstances is the stroke changing in Illustrator? What are you doing to make it change?

Comment: Hi @BillyKerr I am trying to import a SVG file in Adobe XD its a tool for UI Designs, I am able to import in Ai but I don't want to change its stroke when I try to transform the iocns/ SVG.

Comment: It is **very** hard to understand what you are asking. Both XD and AI allow one to expand strokes... Your question *specifically* shows you *already know* how to accomplish that in *both* applications. So, it's near impossible to understand what you are asking. Are you seeking some way to auto-expand strokes when you *open* artwork? That's not going to happen. Adobe earnestly tries not to alter *anything* merely by opening ("importing") a file. In other words, you **can't** avoid the stroke expanding step.. it *must* be done on one of the applications.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about XD, but in Illustrator...

Transform Panel, or Preferences > General and *untick* `Scale Strokes & Effects`

[image]

<sub>(You may need to choose `Show Options` from the Transform Panel Menu to see the checkbox.)</sub>

[image]

Comment: Transform settings in Illustrator won't affect how an SVG behaves in XD though. I'm not sure what the OP is asking TBH.  Maybe he is trying to Expand the strokes?

Comment: @Scott Thank you for your answer, but in my case it did not work. I am basically asking an alternate way of Object > Path > Outline Stroke. The answer you gave worked but only in Ai not in Adobe XD.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the update. It sounds like you are trying to Expand the strokes of icons in Illustrator so they don't resize when scaling in XD.

Basically, select the icon and do **Object > Expand**. This will convert the strokes to outlines with a fill.

Here's an example. On the left is an icon with a stroke, on the right the strokes are Expanded.

[image]

When you export this as an SVG, and use it in XD, the lines will not change disproportionately if you rescale the icon.

Please remember this is a destructive process which can't be undone in Illustrator - for example if you ever want to change the width of the strokes. So, make sure you don't overwrite your original artwork file.

Comment: I *thought* this as well.. but the question states "*I know I can do the same in Ai as well*" and the screenshot shows one way to expand strokes in AI. So I assumed the user didn't need that explained?? We may never know `:)`

Comment: @Scott - yeah, but the OP mentions a different method of doing it. And expand is different from what he mentions. Yeah I agree we may never know. So many X-Y Problems here recently!